# can I use FUSE with Cython bindings

Tags: python, c, cython, fuse

I know FUSE has bindings for C, C++, Python etc. Which effectively means that I can develop FUSE filesystems using those languages.
I wish to use Cython, as it offers much faster speeds as compared to pure Python. That is stressed in a filesystem. Is it possible to produce a FUSE filesystem by coding in Cython?

As far as I understand, Python documentation is all that I require to write Cython code for FUSE. But (if it is indeed possible) should I be using Cython as a Python FUSE system or C system??

Answer (score 0):

You should use it as a Python Fuse System, then you can write your cython stuff in it's own module and just import that module in your python code. Usually file system related operations are IO bound and not CPU bound so I'm not sure how much of a speedup you would get with cython, but I guess try out and compare the results.